# How to create corpus or corpora for classifying text in NLTK?

Tags: python, nltk, classification, corpus

I'm building a classifier text.

1, Have 10 categories, each category have more relative keywords.
2, Now, I have a text. I need classify it into one category
3, I use NLTK but I don't know how to create best train corpus, corpora

Can someone help me with methods to extract features,... tks u

Comment: This question is not a duplicate. The linked question is about a plaintext corpus, but a classification corpus needs to specify categories (the `CategorizedCorpusReader` class), which has additional requirements.